# Export attribute set and the attributes that are assigned to it

Tags: magento2, attributes, csv, importexport

our attribute sets have become messy, things are assigned to them that shouldnt be and some things that should be havent. Is it possible for me to export to CSV the attribute set name and a list of attributes assigned to it? export from magento2

Edit:

I just want to export the attribute set and the attributes assigned to it. for example a clothing store might show.

**T-shirts**

1. Colour
2. Size
3. Brand
4. style
5. pattern

ETC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can export

**Step 1:** Magento Admin Panel

**Step 2:** Go to System Tab then click on Export

**Step 3:** Select Entity Type as Products

**Step 4:** At the bottom click on continue and export

Comment: thanks for the answer Arun but this will export the products with the attribute labels in the top. I just want to export the attribute set and the attributes assigne to it. for example. 

T-shirts

Colour
size
brand